# Changing how the jump section `[` and `]` command works

Tags: cursor-movement

`:help section` states:

> The "]" and "[" commands stop at the '{' or '}' in the first column.  This is
>   useful to find the start or end of a function in a C program.

Is it possible to change the `[` and `]` commands to jump to a different character or pattern. For example in Markdown, I would like sections defined as titles, lines beginning with `#` aka the pattern `^#`. Similarly in Haskell, I would like it to jump to the next/previous type definition (line containing `::`). Both would be set in their respective `ftplugin` files.

I have tried using `map ]] /^#<CR>w` but this does not seem to work as expected and leaves text highlighted. It seems like there would be a better way to achieve this.

Is this possible and if so, how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I stole and renamed the function below from `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`
:

```
function! CustomJump(motion) range
    let cnt = v:count1
    let save = @/
    mark '
    while cnt > 0
        silent! execute a:motion
        let cnt = cnt - 1
    endwhile
    call histdel('/', -1)
    let @/ = save
endfunction
```

and I use it like this in `after/ftplugin/javascript.vim` to jump from function definition to function definition:

```
nnoremap <buffer> ]] :call CustomJump('/function')<cr>
nnoremap <buffer> [[ :call CustomJump('?function')<cr>
```

You could use it like this for markdown:

```
nnoremap <buffer> ]] :call CustomJump('/^#')<cr>
nnoremap <buffer> [[ :call CustomJump('?^#')<cr>
```

or like that for haskell:

```
nnoremap <buffer> ]] :call CustomJump('/::')<cr>
nnoremap <buffer> [[ :call CustomJump('?::')<cr>
```

---

But don't forget the awesome `:global` command:

```
:g/func/#
:g/^#/#
:g/::/#
```

Comment: If my Vim version has `:keepjumps`, could I remove `mark '`, and if I have `:keeppatterns` could I remove `let save = @/` and `call histdel('/', -1) let @/ = save` and replace `silent! execute a:motion` with something like         `silent! execute 'keepjumps keeppatterns ' . a:motion`?

Comment: Maybe, but you would trade portability for virtually no benefit.

Comment: I completely misunderstood the purpose of `mark '`, I thought it was to prevent the jumplist to be modified. But in fact, I think it's the opposite, it's for adding an entry in the jumplist so that you can come back to where you were with `''` or ``, sorry. Anyway this is some great code! With this, you can define with autocommands different type of sections for different filetypes.

Comment: I'm curious: should that be `histdel('/', -1)` or `histdel('search', -1)`?

Comment: @muru, both values are correct, use the one you prefer. See `:help hist-names`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`vim-markdown` plugin](https://github.com/gabrielelana/vim-markdown) has [a function](https://github.com/gabrielelana/vim-markdown/blob/master/ftplugin/markdown.vim#L95) for this in Markdown files:

```
function! s:JumpToHeader(forward, visual)
  let pattern = '\v^#{1,6}.*$|^.+\n%(\-+|\=+)$'
  if a:visual
    normal! gv
  endif
  if a:forward
    let direction = '/'
  else
    let direction = '?'
  endif
  execute 'silent normal! ' . direction . pattern . "\n"
endfunction
```

It matches both [ATX](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.22/#atx-headers) and [setext](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.22/#setext-header) headers (`# foo` as well as `foo` with `---` below it). The function is [mapped by default](https://github.com/gabrielelana/vim-markdown/blob/master/ftplugin/markdown.vim#L144) to `[[` and `]]` by the plugin. However, it could benefit from a call to `histdel()` (as seen in [romainl's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6074/205)).